Trigger TestNG test failure from JMS message
Under TestNG I'm trying to make a test fail when a message is received via jakarta.jms-api-3.1.0
The connection is set up & the MessageConsumer is started.
During a test method, the main app sends a message.
The test method receives it & throws AssertionError().
TestNGcustomListener.onTestFailure is called as expected
and the test suite results show the failure.
Next, to detect messages throughout the test, a MessageListener is attached to the MessageConsumer.
      consumer.setMessageListener(
      (MessageListener)
          new MessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
              throw new AssertionError();
            }
          });

message is received but the AssertionError  isn't detected by TestNGcustomListener
and doesn't produce any output, it seems to be caught elsewhere, and the test doesn't fail,
even if the AssertionError is thrown in a method annotated by @Test.
Any suggestions appreciated.

One solution is to write MessageListener messages to a List then monitor that at every step in the @Test code
